# Failing to read mapped drive as a service, but not when run interactively

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions, windows-service

I have program that reads/writes to a mapped drive. 
It works properly when accessing the mapped drive if I run it interactively (e.g. double click or command line), however it fails if run as a service. (Works fine as a service if I am only accessing local drives)

There is no difference in the program code being executed in either mode, only that it cannot access mapped drives as a service.

I have tested the service running as LocalSystem, LocalService, NetworkService, and set to login as the same user account used to run it interactively, none work.

Are there additional permissions to look for? I had thought having it run as a user it would inherit all of their rights.

Environment is Wondows Server with Active Directory accounts.

Comment: Eric's answer solved the problem, however, since I can't force the mapped drives I altered the service to substitute the UNC path whenever it encounters the mapped drive path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not trying to be short, but i think this will answer your question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182750/how-to-map-a-network-drive-to-be-used-by-a-service

See the one about using the Sys Internals tools